# MySQL Query Multiple Tables w/Same Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

[image]I need to query the same table `users` from multiple tables that share the same foreign key that reference `users`.

I currently have this:

```
SELECT `vendorEmployeeID` AS "Vendor #", CONCAT(`lastName`,", ", `firstName`) AS "Name", `CLINTitle` AS "Position", `iterationName` AS "Exercise", CONCAT(`iterationStart`, " - ", `iterationEnd`) AS "Start - End", CONCAT("Team ", `teamNumber`, " - ", `firstName`) AS "Team Number - Manager", `branchName`, `companyName`
FROM users
INNER JOIN `userassignedteam` ON `users`.`userID` = `userassignedteam`.`assignedUserFK`
INNER JOIN `positions` ON `userassignedteam`.`assigendPositionFK` =  `positions`.`positionID`
INNER JOIN `subteamleaders` ON `userassignedteam`.`userAssignedTeamID` = `subteamleaders`.`subTeamLeadersID`
INNER JOIN `iterationinfo` ON `subteamleaders`.`iterationInfoFK` = `iterationinfo`.`iterationInfoID`
INNER JOIN `contractiterations` ON `iterationinfo`.`iterationFK` = `contractiterations`.`contractIterationID`
INNER JOIN `teams` ON `iterationinfo`.`teamFK` = `teams`.`teamID`
INNER JOIN `companybranches` ON `teams`.`branchFK` = `companybranches`.`branchID`
INNER JOIN `company` ON `companybranches`.`companyFK` = `company`.`companyID`
```

The query works to an extent, but the obvious problem is that I need the the names (firstName, lastName) from table `teams` to show the manager of that team, who is also a user in the table `users`, while at the same time show the team members (because they are never the same) that are also from the table `users` but are recorded in a separate table, `userassignedteam`.

Comment: ffor every user you need to joian another users table with different aliases, but without seeing your tables you have to do it yourself, the vital part are the **different aliases**

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add the image of tables, but I guess I forgot. It has been added. I have tried that, but for some reason, at some point I get an error saying that a column name can't be identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want more joins to the `users` table. Your diagram suggests:

```
SELECT 
    u.vendorEmployeeID AS vendor_number, 
    CONCAT(u.lastName, ', ', u.firstName) AS name, 
    CLINTitle AS position, 
    ci.iterationName AS exercise, 
    CONCAT(ii.iterationStart, ' - ', ii.iterationEnd) AS start_end, 
    CONCAT('Team ', t.teamNumber, ' - ', um.firstName) AS team_number_manager, 
    cb.branchName, 
    c.companyName,
    ut.firstName assigned_user_name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN userassignedteam uat  ON u.userID = uat.assignedUserFK
INNER JOIN positions p           ON uat.assigendPositionFK =  positions.positionID
INNER JOIN subteamleaders stl    ON uat.userAssignedTeamID = stl.subTeamLeadersID
INNER JOIN iterationinfo ii      ON stl.iterationInfoFK = ii.iterationInfoID
INNER JOIN contractiterations ci ON ii.iterationFK = ci.contractIterationID
INNER JOIN teams t               ON ii.teamFK = t.teamID
INNER JOIN companybranches cb    ON t.branchFK = cb.branchID
INNER JOIN company c             ON cb.companyFK = c.companyID
INNER JOIN users um              ON um.userID = t.teamManagerFK
INNER JOIN users ut              ON ut.userID = uat.assignedUserFK
```

Notes:

- you need table aliases to be able to join the same table more than once; I added them to *all* of your tables; you can see why this is a good practice, because it shortens the query and makes it far more readable (hence maintainable)
- in a multi-table query, always prefix each and every column names with the (alias of the) table it belongs to; this makes the query self-explanatory as regard to the underlying data structures - and, again, improves maintainability (I could not tell from which table column `CLINTitle` comes from though, you will have to figure it out by yourself)

Comment: The reason I posted without aliases, is because when I use aliases, I eventually get an error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'users.userID' in 'on clause'`. Your solution, while I agree should work, has produced this error as well.

Comment: Your solution specifically and initially errors to: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONCAT(u.lastName, ', ', u.firstName) AS name,
    CLINTitle AS position,
  ' at line 3`

Comment: @RyanSteiger: that's just a missing comma at the end of the preceding line. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

As you need two user you need to add th users as needed.

As Tip use aliases for all tables, that amles it easier to read and write.

Anoher point, images are always bas .the foeirgnkey are not really visible, and what os worse, to help i need to tyoe the text, what cost very much time

```
SELECT 
    u.`vendorEmployeeID` AS 'Vendor #',
    CONCAT(u.`lastName`, ', ', u.`firstName`) AS 'Name',
    `CLINTitle` AS 'Position',
    `iterationName` AS 'Exercise',
    CONCAT(`iterationStart`, ' - ', `iterationEnd`) AS 'Start - End',
    CONCAT('Team ',
            `teamNumber`,
            ' - ',
            u1.`firstName`) AS 'Team Number - Manager',
    `branchName`,
    `companyName`
FROM
    users u
        INNER JOIN
    `userassignedteam` ON u.`userID` = `userassignedteam`.`assignedUserFK`
        INNER JOIN
    `positions` ON `userassignedteam`.`assigendPositionFK` = `positions`.`positionID`
        INNER JOIN
    `subteamleaders` ON `userassignedteam`.`userAssignedTeamID` = `subteamleaders`.`subTeamLeadersID`
        INNER JOIN
    `iterationinfo` ON `subteamleaders`.`iterationInfoFK` = `iterationinfo`.`iterationInfoID`
        INNER JOIN
    `contractiterations` ON `iterationinfo`.`iterationFK` = `contractiterations`.`contractIterationID`
        INNER JOIN
    `teams` ON `iterationinfo`.`teamFK` = `teams`.`teamID`
    INNER JOIN users u1
     ON u1.userID = `teams`.`teamMAnagerFK`
        INNER JOIN
    `companybranches` ON `teams`.`branchFK` = `companybranches`.`branchID`
        INNER JOIN
    `company` ON `companybranches`.`companyFK` = `company`.`companyID`
```

Comment: I don't know what it is. I've tried that previously, which is why I posted here, but yours states error (initially) ambiguous for venderEmployeeID, so when I specify users by using alias to take care of that error, then I get: `#1054 - Unknown column 'users.userID' in 'on clause'`. That is the problem I've been running into when using aliases. at some point, the query fails because of an "unknown column", even though I feel as though I've identified it appropriately. Any ideas?

Comment: the table user no is called u and you need to used it before every user u table.see changed answer

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked too. I wish I could give you the "Solved" as well, but the other gentleman's solution was first. I gave you a thumbs up for all your comments though. I appreciate your insight and time, sincerely.

Comment: @RyanSteiger upvote helpful answera and accept the one you like